# Exclude scrollbar dimensions from percentages?

Tags: html, css, width, scrollbar

1. Given:

   - elements `parent`, `child1`, `child2`
   - `child2` has `height` and `overflow` set so that its content appears with a vertical scrollbar
   - `child1` and `child2` each have child elements with `width` set using percentage

It appears that 100% of `child2`'s width does not include the vertical scrollbar (testing in Chrome, although ideally I want a cross-browser solution).  In other words:

TL;DR

**If only one of `parent.child1` and `parent.child2` has a vertical scrollbar, then a child element of `child1` has a different computed width than a child element of `child2`.**

How can I arrange `parent`, `child1`, `child2`, and any children of `child1` and `child2` so that the width computed using percentages of `child1` and `child2` are the same??

Solutions can use tricks with absolute positioning of background layers, etc, and "modern" (ie not as widely supported) HTML5/CSS3.

Please and thank you!

Comment: It seems to [work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/SQfka/).  How would you change this?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Regarding the link to [the jsfiddle you posted](http://jsfiddle.net/SQfka/), you did not test with _child_ elements of `child1` and `child2` as I described in my original post.

When I run your fiddle on my browser, I get width 495px for `parent` , `child1`, and `child2`.

Check out [my updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJhay/1/) which displays the behavior I'm talking about.  When `parent` is 495px, `child1` is 495px and `child2` is 495px, but `child1a` is 478px and `child2a` is 495px.

I want `child1a`'s 100% width to _not_ subtract scrollbar width.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you'll need to "double bag" the children for this to work consistently how you'd like it to, applying percentage `width`s to the outer layer and `height`/`overflow` to the inner layer.

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div id="child-1" class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
         <!--- HTML goes here -->
      </div>
    </div>
   <div id="child-2" class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
         <!--- HTML goes here -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

#child-1 { width:60%; }
   #child-1 .inner { height:100px; overflow:auto; }
#child-2 { width:40%; }
```